# How to address Supervisor With Constant Post-Nasal Drip?

Tags: distractions

I have a supervisor that seems to always be suffering from post-nasal drip. They make very noticeable "wet" nasal snorts throughout the day, followed often by a guttural throat clearing. It's very nauseating.

What's the best way to handle this sort of situation, especially at a smaller company?

Comment: Delicately :)  It's possible your supervisor is self conscious about it already.  Has it been going on for long?  Could it be hay fever, perhaps?

Comment: Buy a white noise machine. It will help you focus. http://www.amazon.com/Marpac-DOHM-DS-Natural-actual-Machine/dp/B000KUHFGM
We have them all over our office and they work great. we have the ones that go in the ceiling though. http://soundmasking-whitenoise.com/p/machine-package/

Comment: @crh225 Or just simply listen to music with noise cancelling headphones :)

Comment: @JaneS true but not all workplaces allow headphones. If one proposed a 40 dollar white noise machine that increased my productivity, I would let them buy/use it if I was a manager.

Comment: @Janes - I think it's a long-term thing. Headphones seem to be the best thing so far. I suppose I just need to deal with it during times when I can't wear headphones, like conversations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not likely a professional adult isn't aware of this nauseating behavior (Of course there is some edge-case exception.). More than likely, they chose not to get treatment or there isn't anything that is very effective. Drugs can cause side-effects that may not be conducive to working (drowsiness).

You can confront them and share your disgust, but I doubt there is anything your supervisor can or is willing to do about it.

Then again, some people are just disgusting and need to be shunned..

Answer (score 1):

> What's the best way to handle this sort of situation, especially at a
>   smaller company?

Unless you somehow know that your supervisor is unaware of her/his condition, the only things you can do (practically speaking) are ignore it or leave.